if there is a surjection between sets, is any injection between them also a surjection
Suppose we have $f:X \to Y$ such that $f$ is surjective. Is an injective function $g:X \to Y$ necessarily surjective?
Related to this, suppose we have $X,Y$ well-ordered, and a surjective function $f: S_a \to Y$ for $S_a$ a section of $X$. Is it possible to have an order preserving function from $X$ to $Y$?

Let $X   =\{1,2,3, ...\}$ and $Y = \{0,1,2,3,...\}$.
For the first question: No, it is not necessary that just because there exists a surjection from $X$ to $Y$ that each injection is necessarily surjective:
We see that $f: X \to Y$ by $f(n) = n - 1$ is a surjection, but the injection $g: X \to Y$ given by $g(n) = 2n$ is not surjective.
I do think you claim is true if $X$ and $Y$ are finite, however. (A surjection from $X$ to $Y$ implies that $|X| \ge |Y|$. If there is also an injection from $X$ to $Y$, then $|X| \le |Y|$ and so any injection or surjection from one to the other is in fact a bijection.)
For the second question. Let $S_a = \{2,3,4,...\}$. Then, $f: S_a \to Y$ by $f(n) = n-2$ is a surjection. And clearly, we have an order preserving bijection from $X$ to $Y$ -- namely $n \mapsto  n-1$. (Unless you mean something more technical about a "section" of $X$ that I missed...)
Below Added to respond to OP Clarification
Consider $X = Y = \{0,1,2,..., \omega, \omega + 1, \omega + 2, ... \}$. The function $f: S_\omega \to Y$ defined by sending the $n$th odd number to $\omega + (n-1)$ and the $n$th even -- counting 0 as the 1st even--to $n-1$ is surjective (but not order preserving, of course). But the identity function from $X$ to $Y$ is order preserving.

@ArturoMagidin  Yes they are.. thank you, and fixed!

Thank you for this answer. For the second question I mean a section as a $S_a = {x \in X: x<a}$.
